# Looking for some Interesting C# Programming Problems

Tags: c#

I am tired of doing typical CRUD programming type applications. I would like to work on some interesting (not too hard) programming problems.  Are there any sites out there to help me exercise my brain?

Answer (score 17):

Project Euler: http://projecteuler.net/ is a nice collection of randomly interesting problems.

Somewhat related (not always programming, but generally interesting to programmers) is the IBM ponder this site: http://domino.research.ibm.com/Comm/wwwr_ponder.nsf/pages/index.html

Answer (score 11):

One other great site is ... stackoverflow.com :)

There are some really great questions asked on this site.  I find it fun to pick some of the questions and develop answers for them.  Often I pick a theme.  For instance for the last week, I've tried to solve as many problems as possible using only a single LINQ expression.

Answer (score 3):

Check [DotNetPerls](http://dotnetperls.com/) they have a good selection of problems and solutions focusing in C# programming.

I also like the [C# Brainteasers](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html) from Jon Skeet, good code snippets to read and learn more about the language, some have very interesting and surprising results...

Answer (score 2):

I've used the problems on [Ruby Quiz](http://rubyquiz.com/) before. Other than that Dave Thomas' [CodeKata](http://codekata.com/) and see if there is a [Coding Dojo](http://codingdojo.org/) near you.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout for [CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/)
Interesting problems here any language vl do

Answer (score 1):

Try [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/) they have a good amount of problems for you to work on.  They also vary in difficulty.