# Algorithm to find next greater permutation of a given string

Tags: algorithm

I want an efficient algorithm to find the next greater permutation of the given string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352203/generating-permutations-lazily

Comment: What does `the next greater permutation` mean? I came from Leetcode, want to search the meaning of this thing.

Comment: @JW.ZG Given a number n, find the smallest number that has same set of digits as n and is greater than n.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-next-greater-number-set-digits/

Comment: To phrase this question more formally: A string (or any kind of sequence) has a length ℓ, and has 2 to the power ℓ [permutations](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). E.g. string `"abc"` has permutations `"abc"`, `"acb"`, `"bac"`, `"bca"`, `"cab"`, and `"cba"`. Strings can be [lexicographically ordered](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), e.g. `"acb"` would come before `"cab"` but after `"abc"` in a dictionary. My example list is lexicographically ordered. The _next greater_ permutation is the one that would appear _earliest_ in the dictionary, but _after_ the given permutation.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Wikipedia has a nice [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) on lexicographical order generation. It also describes an algorithm to generate the next permutation.

Quoting:

The following algorithm generates the next permutation lexicographically after a given permutation. It changes the given permutation in-place.

> 1. Find the highest index `i` such that `s[i] < s[i+1]`. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
> 2. Find the highest index `j > i` such that `s[j] > s[i]`. Such a `j` must exist, since `i+1` is such an index.
> 3. Swap `s[i]` with `s[j]`.
> 4. Reverse the order of all of the elements after index `i` till the last element.

Comment: for those who are wondering why the step 4 is not sort: step 1 already implies that from s[i+1] to the end it is already in the descending order, hence reverse is equivalent to sort

Comment: Step 4 is just to make sure that string is next least array. 
For ex .. for arr= [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0].. up to step 3 it will be [6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2 , 2, 1, 0] and step 4 will result to [6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2] which is expected.

Comment: How does it go for [9,5,8,2]?  What is the value of `j`?

Comment: I had the same idea, but it doesn't work for "dkhc". it would return "kcdh" but the correct answer is "hcdk".

Answer (score 24):

A great solution that works is described here: https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm. And the solution that, if next permutation exists, returns it, otherwise returns `false`:

```js
function nextPermutation(array) {
    var i = array.length - 1;
    while (i > 0 && array[i - 1] >= array[i]) {
        i--;
    }

    if (i <= 0) {
        return false;
    }

    var j = array.length - 1;

    while (array[j] <= array[i - 1]) {
        j--;
    }

    var temp = array[i - 1];
    array[i - 1] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;

    j = array.length - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Using the source cited by [@Fleischpfanzerl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287643/rishat):

[image]

We follow the steps as below to find the next lexicographical permutation:

```py
nums = [0,1,2,5,3,3,0]
curr = nums[-1]
pivot = -1
for items in nums[-2::-1]:
    if items >= curr:
        pivot -= 1
        curr = items
    else:
        break
if pivot == - len(nums):
    print('break')     # The input is already the last possible permutation

j = len(nums) - 1
while nums[j] <= nums[pivot - 1]:
    j -= 1
nums[j], nums[pivot - 1] = nums[pivot - 1], nums[j]
nums[pivot:] = nums[pivot:][::-1]
```

the output for sample array `[0,1,2,5,3,3,0]` is

```
[0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 5]
```

So the idea is:
The idea is to follow steps -

1. Find a index 'pivot' from the end of the array such that nums[i - 1] < nums[i]
2. Find index j, such that nums[j] > nums[pivot - 1]
3. Swap both these indexes
4. Reverse the suffix starting at pivot

Answer (score 6):

Homework?  Anyway, can look at the C++ function std::next_permutation, or this:

http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/04/lexicographic-permutations-using.html

Answer (score 2):

We can find the next largest lexicographic string for a given string S using the following step.

```
1. Iterate over every character, we will get the last value i (starting from the first character) that satisfies the given condition S[i] < S[i + 1]
2. Now, we will get the last value j such that S[i] < S[j]
3. We now interchange S[i] and S[j]. And for every character from i+1 till the end, we sort the characters. i.e., sort(S[i+1]..S[len(S) - 1])
```

The given string is the next largest lexicographic string of `S`. One can also use `next_permutation` function call in C++.

Answer (score 1):

nextperm(a, n)

```
1. find an index j such that a[j….n - 1] forms a monotonically decreasing sequence.
2. If j == 0 next perm not possible
3. Else 
    1. Reverse the array a[j…n - 1]
    2. Binary search for index of a[j - 1] in a[j….n - 1]
    3. Let i be the returned index
    4. Increment i until a[j - 1] < a[i]
    5. Swap a[j - 1] and a[i]


O(n) for each permutation.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Solution::nextPermutation(vector<int> &a) {    
int i, j=-1, k, n=a.size();
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) if(a[i] < a[i+1]) j=i;
if(j==-1) reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
else {
    for(i=j+1; i<n; i++) if(a[j] < a[i]) k=i;
    swap(a[j],a[k]);
    reverse(a.begin()+j+1, a.end());
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a great tutorial.
link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quAS1iydq7U

```
void Solution::nextPermutation(vector<int> &a) {


int k=0;
int n=a.size();
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    if(a[i]<a[i+1])
    {
        k=i;
    }
}

int ele=INT_MAX;
int pos=0;
for(int i=k+1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>a[k] && a[i]<ele)
    {
        ele=a[i];pos=i;
    }

}

if(pos!=0)
{

swap(a[k],a[pos]);

reverse(a.begin()+k+1,a.end()); 

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A great solution that works is described here: https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm. 
and if you are looking for

**source code:**

```
/**
     * method to find the next lexicographical greater string
     * 
     * @param w
     * @return a new string
     */
    static String biggerIsGreater(String w) {
        char charArray[] = w.toCharArray();
        int n = charArray.length;
        int endIndex = 0;

        // step-1) Start from the right most character and find the first character
        // that is smaller than previous character.
        for (endIndex = n - 1; endIndex > 0; endIndex--) {
            if (charArray[endIndex] > charArray[endIndex - 1]) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // If no such char found, then all characters are in descending order
        // means there cannot be a greater string with same set of characters
        if (endIndex == 0) {
            return "no answer";
        } else {
            int firstSmallChar = charArray[endIndex - 1], nextSmallChar = endIndex;

            // step-2) Find the smallest character on right side of (endIndex - 1)'th
            // character that is greater than charArray[endIndex - 1]
            for (int startIndex = endIndex + 1; startIndex < n; startIndex++) {
                if (charArray[startIndex] > firstSmallChar && charArray[startIndex] < charArray[nextSmallChar]) {
                    nextSmallChar = startIndex;
                }
            }

            // step-3) Swap the above found next smallest character with charArray[endIndex - 1]
            swap(charArray, endIndex - 1, nextSmallChar);

            // step-4) Sort the charArray after (endIndex - 1)in ascending order
            Arrays.sort(charArray, endIndex , n);

        }
        return new String(charArray);
    }

    /**
     * method to swap ith character with jth character inside charArray
     * 
     * @param charArray
     * @param i
     * @param j
     */
    static void swap(char charArray[], int i, int j) {
        char temp = charArray[i];
        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
        charArray[j] = temp;
    }
```

If you are looking for video explanation for the same, you can visit [here](https://youtu.be/BMbeeB_57Pk).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved just by using two simple algorithms searching and find smaller element in just O(1) extra space and O(nlogn ) time and also easy to implement .

To understand this approach clearly . Watch this Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DREZ9pb8EQI

Answer (score 0):

```
def result(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        for p in result(remLst):
            l.append([m] + p)
    return l
result(['1', '2', '3'])
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Start traversing from the end of the list. Compare each one with the previous index value.
2. If the previous index (say at index `i-1`) value, consider `x`, is lower than the current index (index `i`) value, sort the sublist on right side starting from current position `i`.
3. Pick one value from the current position till end which is **just higher than** `x`,  and put it at index `i-1`. At the index the value was picked from, put `x`.  That is:

   `swap(list[i-1], list[j])  where j >= i, and the list is sorted from index "i" onwards`

Code:

```
public void nextPermutation(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    for (int i = a.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
        if (a.get(i) > a.get(i-1)){
            Collections.sort(a.subList(i, a.size()));
            for (int j = i; j < a.size(); j++){
                if (a.get(j) > a.get(i-1)) {
                    int replaceWith = a.get(j); // Just higher than ith element at right side.
                    a.set(j, a.get(i-1));
                    a.set(i-1, replaceWith);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // It means the values are already in non-increasing order. i.e. Lexicographical highest
    // So reset it back to lowest possible order by making it non-decreasing order.
    for (int i = 0, j = a.size()-1; i < j; i++, j--){
        int tmp = a.get(i);
        a.set(i, a.get(j));
        a.set(j, tmp);
    }
}
```

Example :

```
10 40 30 20 => 20 10 30 40  // 20 is just bigger than 10

10 40 30 20 5 => 20 5 10 30 40 // 20 is just bigger than 10.  Numbers on right side are just sorted form of this set {numberOnRightSide - justBigger + numberToBeReplaced}.
```

Answer (score -8):

I hope this code might be helpful.

```
int main() {

    char str[100];
    cin>>str;
    int len=strlen(len);
    int f=next_permutation(str,str+len);    
    if(f>0) {
        print the string
    } else {
        cout<<"no answer";
    }
}
```