# Python itertools permutations with double elements

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, python-itertools

I'm using python (2.7.2) and I need all permutations without repetition from a list. More precisely,

```
 for i in itertools.permutations([1,2,3]): print i
```

correctly gives

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

But now I am looking for something would do the following

```
for i in myfunction([1,2,2]): print i
(1,2,2)
(2,2,1)
(2,1,2)
```

Whereas itertools would give that list twice (or, for ([1,1,1]) as the input, it is just repeated six times).
This is basically something between itertools.permutations and itertools.combinations. 
I tried working with sets, but all solutions that I tried always created new problems and never matched the desired output.

Comment: Can't you just filter the result through a `set`? `for i in set(itertools.permutations([1,2,2])): print i`

Comment: Works. Thanks, somehow failed to get there in the beginning and ended up in way to complicated solutions.

Comment: There's an efficient way to do that in [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31678111/4014959)

Comment: Impressive algorithm, but way above the demands of my program.

Comment: I'll add a modified version of that code here, since that question is somewhat different to yours.

Comment: The sympy library has an iterator for this. Please see my answer (just added) in the question that @tobias_k just referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the set.

```
s = []
for i in itertools.permutations([1,2,2]):
    s.append(i)
print(set(s))
```

Which gives:

```
{(1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2)}
```

Alternatively, without saving the objects to a variable:

```
for i in set(itertools.permutations([1,2,2])):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just insert directly into the set? What is the purpose of the list?

Comment: I edited my response to include the direct method but the reason was to show how keep an object with the desired information.

Comment: Why would you need to save the objects?