# Permutation algorithm analysis

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I've been studying algorithms like crazy for a big interview. This particular algorithm is driving me crazy I've added comments to some lines that don't understand.

```
def permute(s):
    out = []

    if len(s) == 1:
        # wouldn't setting out replace everything in out?
        out = [s]

    else:
        for i, let in enumerate(s):

            # how does it know that I only want 2 strings?
            for perm in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):

                out += [let + perm]

    return out

print permute("cat")
```

Is it correct to say that the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n!)?

Comment: As an aside - In an interview the interviewer does not usually care if you get the correct answer. What they are trying to find out how you approach a problem.

Comment: It's actually a little worse than O(n!), [A002627](https://oeis.org/A002627) gives the sequence: 1, 3, 10, 41, 206, 1237, 8660, ...

Comment: I don't get this comment: "# how does it know that I only want 2 strings?" `s[:i] + s[i+1:]` creates a single string which is a copy of `s` with the char at index `i` removed.

Comment: As for your 1st comment, bear in mind that each recursive call to `permute` gets its own fresh `out` list.

Comment: I would actually change `out = [s]` to `return [s]`. It's a base case and returning directly from it seems clearer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially out is defined inside the context of the permute method, so each call will have its own out vector. So when redefining `out = [s]` you just overriding the `out=[]` inside the method context.

If the input is bigger than one char this is what happens:

```
# Iterate for each char
for i, let in enumerate(s):
    # Iterate for each permutation of the string without the char i
    for perm in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):
            # Put the removed char in the beginning of the permutation
            # and add it to the list.
            out += [let + perm]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a generator version of that algorithm. It's a bit nicer because it doesn't require those `out` lists.

```
def permute(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        yield s
    else:
        for i, let in enumerate(s):
            for perm in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):
                yield let + perm

for s in permute("abc"):
    print(s)
```

**output**

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Of course, it's almost always better to avoid recursion (especially in Python) unless the problem needs recursion (eg processing recursive data structure, like trees). And of course a real Python program would normally use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), unless it needs to correctly handle repeating items in the base sequence. In that case, I recommend the iterative algorithm of Narayana Pandita, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31678111/4014959).