# Iterate over permutations without holding them in memory

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, octave, permutation

Consider I have really big vector (more then 10 elements), and I have to check some stuff over each permutation, but I don't need all permutations being held in memory. Just for example, for vector with 12 elements I got memory troubles:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
>> perms(A)
error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type
```

My question is: is any nice and short method to get all possible permutations over vector like iterator, without holding them all in memory, so I could to make them for arbitrary sized vector and do some stuff over each of them in a loop?

Sure I know how to programm this algorithm on any programming language, but I'm looking for ready solution on octave or Matlab.

Comment: You probably can implement your version of this algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622532/algorithm-to-find-next-greater-permutation-of-a-given-string

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia I've already found nice solution with Heap's algorithm and will post my own answer soon

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia If you are interested, I've published my own solution.