# Generating permutations in lexicographic order in Python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, permutation

I am struggling with the following, is my code correct and how to test if it works?

Task: **Take a string as a single input argument. You may assume the string consists of distinct lower case letters (in alphabetical order).** You may assume the input is a string of letters in alphabetical order.

**Return a list of strings where each string represents a permutation of the input string. The list of permutations must be in lexicographic order.** (This is basically the ordering that dictionaries use. Order by the first letter (alphabetically), if tie then use the second letter, etc.

- If the string contains a single character return a list containing that string
- Loop through all character positions of the string containing the characters to be permuted, for each character:
- Form a simpler string by removing the character
- Generate all permutations of the simpler string recursively
- Add the removed character to the front of each permutation of the simpler
  word, and add the resulting permutation to a list
- Return all these newly constructed permutations

[My code]

```
def perm_gen_lex(in_string):

    if (len(in_string) <= 1):
        return(in_string)

    # List of all new combinations
    empty_list = []

    # All permutations
    final_perm = perm_gen_lex(in_string[1:])

    # Character to be removed
    remove_char = in_string(0)

    # Remaining part of string
    remaining_string = in_string[1:]

    for perm in final_perm[1:]:
        for i in range(len(in_string) + 1):
            return empty_list.append(perm[:i] + remove_char + perm[i:])

    return empty_list
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend taking a look at [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). One, in real world code, it's what you would use, but two, the documentation for it actually includes the Python code that performs the same task, which might be a useful starting point. About the only difference from your code would be that you'd replace the `yield`s with `append`s to your result `list` (because I'm guessing you haven't covered generator functions yet).

Comment: Take a look at this. Provides good understanding on how to write such an algorithm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622532/algorithm-to-find-next-greater-permutation-of-a-given-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find next greater permutation of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622532/algorithm-to-find-next-greater-permutation-of-a-given-string)

Comment: I tried to fix you indentation, please check it. But yeah this is a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

Some variation on this will get you moving:

```
from itertools import product

def combinations(string):
    return [''.join(i) for i in product(string, repeat = len(string))]

print(combinations("abc"))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: You just wrapped `itertools.product` and named it `combinations` (which it isn't). Actual combinations (order-insensitive) don't help with generating permutations (order-sensitive), and products of a repeated input produce many non-permutation outputs (because they contain an item from the string multiple times, while omitting others). And even if this worked, the OP asked for tips; code without explanation is the opposite of what they need.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your constructive feedback ShadowRinger. Please accept my most humble apologies for the sub par offer of direction.

Comment: I am so lost with what you said, I really have tried understanding this. But I am such a beginner that I cant even follow what your doing.  Im still trying to figure out how to make a unittest

Comment: im confused about this line, What does it do ?...  return [''.join(i) for i in product(string, repeat = len(string))]

Comment: The line is wrapped in [ and ] which means its a list comprehension statement. See here for a good explanation of what that is if you aren't familiar with list comprehension: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/. Its a very useful Python concept for writing concise and efficient code and removing for loops.

Comment: The statement product(string, repeat=len(string)] is an itertools function that builds different Cartesian products of the input value. But as ShadowRinger points out - there are more suitable itertools functions for your problem. Itertools is a library that offer some very useful functions for iterating over objects efficiently. There is a quite well explained article on the basic  iteritems functions here https://pymotw.com/2/itertools/. The function you likely want is itertools.permutations.