# How to group items so as not to exceed a total amount in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of n objects in it. Each object has names as id, quantity, price and total. *All of these have significance in solving this problem.*

How can I create new arrays where sum of all `total` of their objects doesn't exceed 150.

**My array:**

```
let array = [{id: 1, quantity: 5, price: 10, total: 50}, {id: 2, quantity: 3, price: 100, total: 300}]
```

**Expected result:**

```
array1 = [{id: 1, quantity: 5, price: 10, total: 50}, {id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 100, total: 100}]
array2 = [{id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 100, total: 100}]
array3 = [{id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 100, total: 100}]
```

**Conditions:**

1. As mentioned, sum of `total`s in new arrays mustn't exceed 150
2. value of `total` must always be product of `quantity` and `price` in that object
3. object must keep dividing itself into new objects with smaller quantities until above conditions are met
4. `quantity` must be an integer

**i tried this.**

```
const itemsFinals = [];
const maxTotal = 150;
let totalGroup = 0;
for (i = 0; i < itemComprobantes.length; i++) {
    if((itemComprobantes[i].total  + totalGroup) < maxTotal){
        itemsFinals.push(itemComprobantes[i]);
        totalGroup += itemComprobantes[i].total;
    }
}
```

Comment: why `itemComprobantes[0]` not `itemComprobantes[i]`? it means every loop you're just taking the first element of the array in your current `for loop`

Comment: also this `(itemComprobantes[0].total  + totalGroup)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partitioning weighted elements with a restriction on total partition weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808877/partitioning-weighted-elements-with-a-restriction-on-total-partition-weight)

Comment: are we talking about the **total amount** is the `total` key of each object or the *total* number of elements in array? isn't not that your `totalGroup` should be adding the `total` key only and not the whole object like this? `totalGroup += itemComprobantes[i].total`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let itemComprobantes = [
    {id: 1, quantity: 5, price: 10, total: 50}, 
    {id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 100, total: 100},
    {id: 3, quantity: 1, price: 100, total: 100},
    {id: 4, quantity: 1, price: 100, total: 30},
    {id: 5, quantity: 1, price: 100, total: 80}
  ]

    
    const itemsFinals = {}
    const maxTotal = 150
    let totalGroup = 0
    let group = 1
    
    for (i = 0; i < itemComprobantes.length; i++) {
        if((itemComprobantes[i].total  + totalGroup) > maxTotal){
          group += 1
          totalGroup = 0
        }
        if (itemsFinals['group '+group] === undefined) {
         itemsFinals['group '+group] = []
        }
        itemsFinals['group '+group].push(itemComprobantes[i])
        totalGroup += itemComprobantes[i].total
        
    }
    
    console.log(itemsFinals)
```

Here is my answer base on my comments.

Comment: Thank you, but the expected result is not achieved.

Comment: Can you give more detail on your question? why in your snippet the `maxTotal` is `150` but the first snippet in your question is total of `350`? `let array = [{id: 1, quantity: 5, price: 10, total: 50}, {id: 2, quantity: 3, price: 100, total: 300}]`

Comment: The sum of the totals of each array must not exceed 150 if it exceeds, it is added to the next one.

Comment: I think OP wants you to enter data on the first snippet and get result of second snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. I know its long but give it a try

```js
let array = [{id: 1, quantity: 5, price: 10, total: 50}, {id: 2, quantity: 3, price: 100, total: 300}, {id: 3, quantity: 5, price: 40, total: 200}, {id: 4, quantity: 2, price: 10, total: 20}];

const maxTotal = 150;
let new_arrays = {};
let index = 0;

let final_total = 0;
new_arrays['array_'+index] = [];


for (var obj of array) {
    final_total += obj.total;
    while (final_total > maxTotal) {
        let exceed_value = final_total - maxTotal;      // 350 - 150 = 200
        let retain_quantity = parseInt((obj.total - exceed_value) / obj.price); // (300 - 200)/100 = 2
        let remaining_quantity = obj.quantity - retain_quantity;
        
        if (retain_quantity != 0) {
            retain_obj = Object.assign({}, obj);
            retain_obj.quantity = retain_quantity;
            retain_obj.total = retain_quantity * obj.price;
            new_arrays["array_"+index].push(retain_obj);
        }

        index++;
        new_arrays['array_'+index] = [];
        new_obj = Object.assign({}, obj, {quantity: remaining_quantity, total: remaining_quantity * obj.price})
        new_arrays["array_"+index].push(new_obj);

        // console.log(new_obj);
        obj = new_obj;
        final_total = remaining_quantity * obj.price;

        new_arrays['array_'+index].pop();   // if loop is to repeat again
    }

    new_arrays["array_"+index].push(obj);   // prints new and remaining quantities
}
console.log(new_arrays)
```