# Given a set of characters, how can you display the string with a higher lexicographical order, only by rearranging the characters?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Let's say you have the string `cana`. The string with the lexicographical order higher than that, would be `cnaa`. Is there any way you could do that, faster than just checking from right to left for every character?

Comment: Please show your solution - you may have already found the best one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm to find next greater permutation of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622532/algorithm-to-find-next-greater-permutation-of-a-given-string)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void swap_chars(char &a, char &b) {
  char m = a;
  a = b;
  b = m;
}

std::string next(std::string str) {
  for (int i=str.length()-1; i>0; i--)
    if (str.at(i-1) < str.at(i)) {
      swap_chars(str.at(i-1), str.at(i));
      std::sort(str.begin()+i, str.end());
      break;
    }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `algorithm` you can just just use [`std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end())`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: @jodag I didn't know that. Thank you a lot