# C++ algorithm for N! orderings

Tags: c++, permutation, factorial

I have a list of N items and I am wondering how I can loop through the list to get every combination.  There are no doubles, so I need to get all N! orderings.  Extra memory is no problem, I'm trying to think of the simplest algorithm but I'm having trouble.

Comment: is it combination or permutation?

Comment: See also an explanation of two different algorithms at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352203/generating-permutations-lazily/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: Good call (so to speak). Though to be fair, the OP did ask for the simplest *algorithm*.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on others' answers, here's an example of std::next_permutation adapted from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void outputArray(int* array, int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { cout << array[i] << " "; }
}

int main ()
{
  int myints[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  const int size = sizeof(myints);

  cout << "The 5! possible permutations with 5 elements:\n";

  sort (myints, myints + size);

  bool hasMorePermutations = true;
  do
  {
    outputArray(myints, size);
    hasMorePermutations = next_permutation(myints, myints + size);
  }
  while (hasMorePermutations);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any point in the `bool` variable. You can just `do { ... } while (std::next_permutation(...));`

Comment: @Charles: It's true, I could do that.  For teaching purposes I pulled out the next_permutation since that was the focus of the code.

Comment: Fair enough. Personally, I find it clearer without the extra variable but perhaps that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

C++ STL has [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Simple algorithm using Recursion:

***PSEUDOCODE***

```
getPermutations(CurItemList , CurPermList)

if CurItemList.isempty()
    return CurPermList
else
    Permutations = {}

    for i = 1 to CurItemList.size() 
        CurPermList.addLast(CurItemList.get(i))

        NextItemList = CurItemList.copy()
        NextItemList.remove(i)

        Permutations.add(getPermutations(NextItemList, CurPermList))

        CurPermList.removeLast()


return Permutations

// To make it look better
Permutations(ItemList) 
    return getPermutations(ItemList, {})
```

I didnt test it, but should work. Maybe its not the smartest way to do it, but its an easy way.
If something is wrong please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try building up the set of combinations recursively with a fixed count of possible elements. The set of all possible combinations will be the union of the sets of combinations of 1 element, 2 elements, ... up to N elements.

Then you can attack each fixed sized combination individually.