# Is there any equivalent of c++ std::next_permutation() in c# 2.0?

Tags: c#, c++

Is there any equivalent of [std::next_permutation()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) in c#?

I need to use it in .Net 2.0 but I am still curious to know even if later version are supporting it.

Comment: It is not there, but the STL version is very easy to translate. I've done it for a programming competition many years ago, it's only a couple dozen lines of code.

Comment: To add to dasblinkenlight, here is an [example implementation](http://olsen.org/alan/blog/?p=85).

Comment: Here I implemented it in C# v3 (uses var and generics)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12768718/913845