# Generate number sequences with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I try to write a LINQ statement which returns me all possible combinations of numbers (I need this for a test and I was inspired by this [article of Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/19/every-binary-tree-there-is.aspx)). The method's prototype I call looks like:

```
IEnumerable<Collection<int>> AllSequences( int start, int end, int size );
```

The rules are:

- all returned collections have a length of `size`
- number values within a collection have to increase
- every number between `start` and `end` should be used

So calling the `AllSequences( 1, 5, 3 )` should result in 10 collections, each of size 3:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4 
2 3 5
2 4 5 
3 4 5
```

Now, somehow I'd really like to see a **pure LINQ** solution. I am able to write a non LINQ solution on my own, so please put no effort into a solution without LINQ.
My tries so far ended at a point where I have to join a number with the result of a recursive call of my method - something like:

```
return from i in Enumerable.Range( start, end - size + 1 )
       select BuildCollection(i, AllSequences( i, end, size -1));
```

But I can't manage it to implement `BuildCollection()` on a LINQ base - or even skip this method call. Can you help me here?

Comment: @Noldorin, @Fede: Thanks for the great answers - I definitely have to take a closer look at the methods of `Enumerable` (like `Repeat()` or `Concat()`)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Think I've got it.

```
IEnumerable<List<int>> AllSequences(int start, int end, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return Enumerable.Repeat<List<int>>(new List<int>(), 1);

    return from i in Enumerable.Range(start, end - size - start + 2)
           from seq in AllSequences(i + 1, end, size - 1)
           select new List<int>{i}.Concat(seq).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `if (size == 0) return new int[] { }.ToList()` ?

Answer (score 69):

```
 Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
           .Select(x => (x - 1) + 1);
```

Comment: didn't answer the question, but was useful to me, so +1

Comment: What does this do? Isn't the `.Select` redundant?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes, it seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but answers the google search.

Answer (score 13):

Something like the following should do the job, I think.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> AllSequences(int start, int end,
    int size)
{
    return size <= 0 ? new[] { new int[0] } :
           from i in Enumerable.Range(start, end - size - start + 2)
           from seq in AllSequences(i + 1, end, size - 1)
           select Enumerable.Concat(new[] { i }, seq);
}
```

The key to the solution is the [compound `from` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx), which is quite handy for dealing with nested enumerables.

Notice that I've changed the method signature slightly to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`, since this is more convenient when using (pure) LINQ. You can always convert it easily to a `IEnumerable<ICollection<int>>` at the end if you like, however.

Let me know if the code needs any explanation, but I'm hoping the LINQ syntax makes it reasonably clear.

**Edit 1:** Fixed bug and improved conciseness.

**Edit 2:**
Because I'm bored and have nothing better to do (no, not really), I thought I'd write an extension method that compute the combinations of a given list of elements, making use of the `AllSequences` method.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IList<T> source,
    int num)
{
    return AllSequences(0, source.Count - 1, num).Select(
        seq => seq.Select(i => source[i]));
}
```

Perhaps not the most efficient way of computing combinations, but certainly pretty compact code!

Comment: I just ran it and it causes a stackoverflow :-(, maybe with a where size > 0, just before the second from?

Comment: It needs to be `from seq in AllSequences(i+1, end, size-1)`
Other than that, nice! I just wrote one too, but yours is a lot more concise. +1

Comment: Both this and @Fede's answer yield no results :-(

Comment: @David Archer try var result = Allsequences(1,5,3).ToList();

Comment: Indeed, it has a problem unfortunately. Working to resolve it right now.

Comment: @jonas, no luck, but def not marking down, this is fun :-) +1

Comment: @David, did you put the base case for size == 0 that returns an IEnumerable with a single item, being that item an empty List? I tested with (1, 5, 3) and got the same result as @tanascius posted.

Comment: @tzaman: Cheers for the tip. Sent me more along the right lines. In the spirit of expanding on each other's answer, I've taken the `end - size - start + 2` bit from Fede's answer to give what I think is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks, David. I would agree - this was a joint effort, probably should have been community wiki in the end!

Comment: haha, pedantically it should be if (size <= 0), on both answers, that is :-)

Comment: @David: Yes, but the only case in which that makes a difference is when the method caller is stupid enough to pass it a negative size value anyway hehe.