# Code Golf: All +-*/ Combinations for 3 integers

Tags: math, code-golf

Write a program that takes 3 integers separated by spaces and perform every single combination of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division operations possible and display the result with the operation combination used.

Example:

`$./solution 1 2 3`

Results in the following output

`1+2+3 = 6`

`1-2-3 = -4`

`1*2*3 = 6`

`1/2/3 = 0` (integer answers only, round up at .5)

`1*2-3 = -1`

`3*1+2 = 5`

etc...

Order of operation rules apply, assume there will be no parenthesis used i.e. `(3-1)*2 = 4` is not a combination, although you could implement this for "extra credit"

For results where a divide by 0 occurs simply return NaN

**Edit:** Permuting the input is required, i.e., if the input is `1 2 3`, then `3*1*2` is a valid combination.

Comment: @Flash: Please also follow the spec described in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions/24258#24258

Comment: It's not terribly clear that permuting the input numbers is also necessary. A clarification of that point might help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't this a bit unfair because it benefits greatly from the builtin `eval()`'s of most interpreted languages?

Comment: @Alexander: The C example shows that the preprocessor can be abused to do the eval.

Comment: @Alexander, @SztupY: Java's evilness can also be abused. Really!

Comment: I totally had this problem recently and used C# to write a non-eval approach. Eval makes it a lot easier though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Perl 130 chars

So long as external libraries are permitted:

```
use Algorithm::Permute"permute";
permute{for$x(@a=qw(+ - / *)){for$y(@a){$_="@ARGV";s/ /$x/;s/ /$y/;printf"
$_ = %.0f",eval}}}@ARGV
```

2nd newline is significant.

Without a module, and assuming that all three inputs are distinct, here's another solution:

```
      @n=&             ARGV;
      @o=(            q[+],
      "-",           q{/},         '*'     );;
      for$          {a}(@           n){   for
 $b(@n){for$c(@    {n}){             for $x( 
 @o){for$y(@o){   ($a-$  b)*($a-$c)*  ($b-$
 c)||next;$_=$a  .$x.$   b."$y$c";$%   =42
      /84+      eval;    print"",$_,  "$S="
      ,$S,     $%,$/                 }}} }};
      ;sub    ARGV{                 $S=   $".
      "";@   ARGV}                 ;1+     2+3
```

Answer (score 21):

## Java - 666 characters

<sub>Has also oneliners, luckily we have Eclipse and Netbeans automatic code-format! :-) Also implemented parenthesis (but also contains trivial ops)?</sub>

```
public class CodeGolf{static String[]o={"+","-","/","*"};static void p(N a,int b,N c,int d,N e,int i){System.out.printf("%s%s(%s%s%s) = %s\n",a,o[b],c,o[d],e,new N(a,b,new N(c,d,e)));}public static void main(String[]v){N[]n={new N(v[0]),new N(v[1]),new N(v[2])};for(int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0;m<3;i++,j+=i==4?1:0,i%=4,k+=j==4?1:0,j%=4,l+=k==3?1:0,k%=3,m+=l==3?1:0,l%=3){p(n[k],i,n[l],j,n[m],0);}}static class N{Double v;N(String s){v=v.parseDouble(s);}N(N a,int o,N b){if(a.v==null||b.v==null)return;double x=b.v, y=a.v; switch(o){case 0:x=-x;case 1:v=y-x;return;case 3:v=y*x;x=0;case 2:if(x!=0)v=y/x;}}public String toString(){return v!=null?""+Math.round(v):"NaN";}}}
```

*Expanded, formatted, version with comments*:

```
public class CodeGolf {

// operators
static String[] o = {"+", "-", "/", "*"};

// print
static void p(N a, int b, N c, int d, N e, int i) {
    System.out.printf("%s%s(%s%s%s) = %s\n", a, o[b], c, o[d], e,
            new N(a, b, new N(c, d, e))); // calculate
}

public static void main(String[] v) {
    N[] n = {new N(v[0]), new N(v[1]), new N(v[2])};
    // Nested for-loops? Nah, too much code!
    // Conditional operator, modulus is way cooler.
    for (int i = 0, j = 0,
             k = 0, l = 0, m = 0; m < 3; i++,
                                    j += i == 4 ? 1 : 0,
                                         i %= 4,
                               k += j == 4 ? 1 : 0,
                                    j %= 4,
                          l += k == 3 ? 1 : 0,
                               k %= 3,
                     m += l == 3 ? 1 : 0,
                          l %= 3) {
        p(n[k], i, n[l], j, n[m], 0);
    }
}

// number wrapper
static class N {

    Double v;

    // parse input
    N(String s) {
        v = v.parseDouble(s);
    }

    // calculate input
    N(N a, int o, N b) {
        // NaN's should fall through
        if (a.v == null || b.v == null) {
            return;
        }
        double x = b.v, y = a.v;
        // operator execution
        switch (o) {
            case 0:
                x = -x;
                // fall through; y + x = y - (-x)
            case 1:
                v = y - x;
                return; // break would make it 665 characters, not as cool
            case 3:
                v = y * x;
                x = 0;
                // fall through; no return needed
            case 2:
                if (x != 0) {
                    v = y / x;
                }
                // will NaN because v = null if x = 0
        }
    }

    // rounding and NaN
    public String toString() {
        return v != null ? "" + Math.round(v) : "NaN";
    }
}
```

}

Iterate on both operators (4 * 4) and permute on operands, twice (3! * 2) makes (4 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 2 = 192 possiblities).

<sup>+</sup>/- 2.5 hours :-) Enjoy!

Comment: That's the most evil `for` loop I've ever seen!

Answer (score 17):

## Delphi - <s>838</s> 747 characters

Single Line Version (Original)

```
program p;{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}uses SysUtils;type g=Integer;function a(b,c:g):g;begin a:=b+c;end;function s(b,c:g):g;begin s:=b-c;end;function m(b,c:g):g;begin m:=b*c;end;function d(b,c:g):g;begin d:=b div c;end;type t=function(b,c:g):g;r=record f:t;c:char;p:boolean;end;procedure q(l:Array of g;w,e:r);var b:String;x,y,z:g;begin for x:=0 to 2 do for y:=0 to 2 do for z:=0 to 2 do if not((x=y)or(x=z)or(y=z))then begin try if(w.p)or not(w.p xor e.p)then b:=IntToStr(e.f(w.f(l[x],l[y]),l[z]))else b:=IntToStr(w.f(l[x],e.f(l[y],l[z])));except b:='NaN';end;writeln(l[x],w.c,l[y],e.c,l[z],'=',b);end;end;const O:Array[0..3]of r=((f:a;c:'+';p:false),(f:s;c:'-';p:false),(f:m;c:'*';p :true),(f:d;c:'/';p:true));var L:Array[0..2] of g;I,J:g; begin for I:=0 to 2 do L[I]:=StrToInt(ParamStr(I+1));for I:=0 to 3 do for J:=0 to 3 do q(l,o[I],o[J]);end.
```

Single Line Version (Shortened to 747 Characters)

```
program p;{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}uses SysUtils,Math;type g=integer;t=function(b,c:g):g;r=record f:t;p:boolean;end;function a(b,c:g):g;begin a:=b+c end;function s(b,c:g):g;begin s:=b-c end;function m(b,c:g):g;begin m:=b*c end;function d(b,c:g):g;begin d:=b div c end;const f=true;u=false;n=[1..4];b=[1..3];c='+-*/';O:Array[1..4]of r=((f:a;p:f),(f:s;p:f),(f:m;p:u),(f:d;p:u));var l: Array[1..3]of g;I,J,x,y,z:g;w,e:r;begin for I in b do l[I]:=StrToInt(ParamStr(I));for I in n do for J in n do for x in b do for y in b do for z in b do if not((x=y)or(x=z)or(y=z))then begin w:=O[I];e:=O[J];write(l[x],c[I],l[y],c[J],l[z],'=');try writeLn(ifthen(w.p or not(w.p xor e.p),e.f(w.f(l[x],l[y]),l[z]),w.f(l[x],e.f(l[y],l[z]))))except writeln('NaN')end;end;end.
```

Formated:

```
program p;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

type
  g = Integer;

function a(b, c: g): g;
begin
  a := b + c;
end;

function s(b, c: g): g;
begin
  s := b - c;
end;

function m(b, c: g): g;
begin
  m := b * c;
end;

function d(b, c: g): g;
begin
  d := b div c;
end;

type
  t = function(b, c: g): g;

  r = record
    f: t;
    c: char;
    p: boolean;
  end;

procedure q(l: Array of g; w, e: r);
var
  b: String;
  x, y, z: g;
begin
  for x := 0 to 2 do
    for y := 0 to 2 do
      for z := 0 to 2 do
        if not((x = y) or (x = z) or (y = z)) then
        begin
          try
            if (w.p) or not(w.p xor e.p) then
              b := IntToStr(e.f(w.f(l[x], l[y]), l[z]))
            else
              b := IntToStr(w.f(l[x], e.f(l[y], l[z])));
          except
            b := 'NaN';
          end;
          writeln(l[x], w.c, l[y], e.c, l[z], '=', b);
        end;
end;

const
  O: Array [0..3] of r = ((f: a; c: '+'; p: false), (f: s; c: '-'; p: false),
                            (f: m; c: '*'; p: true), (f: d; c: '/'; p: true));

var
  l: Array [0..2] of g;
  I, J: g;
begin

  for I := 0 to 2 do
    l[I] := StrToInt(ParamStr(I + 1));
  for I := 0 to 3 do
    for J := 0 to 3 do
      q(l, O[I], O[J]);

end.
```

This is by far the ugliest code I have ever written.

Comment: Don't worry, I've made it even worse to get rid of 91 characters :)

Comment: You can still remove the "program" line as it is not needed by the compiler and get rid of the "APPTYPE" as it can be given as a compiler switch in the command line.

Answer (score 16):

### J, 75 <s>55</s> characters.

Outputs rational numbers, not integers.

```
(],"1'=',"1 ":@x:@".)((' ',>@{.),@,.":"0@>@{:)"1>{(,{;~'+-*%');<<"1(i.!3)A.
```

Old version which didn't permute the input (was 55 characters)

```
(],"1'=',"1 ":@x:@".)(>,{;~'+-*%')(' 'I.@:E.s)}"1 s=:":
```

Example (note that J's order of operations is right-to-left):

```
   (],"1'=',"1 ":@x:@".)((' ',>@{.),@,.":"0@>@{:)"1>{(,{;~'+-*%');<<"1(i.!3)A.1 2 3
 1+2+3=6   
 1+3+2=6   
 2+1+3=6   
 2+3+1=6   
 3+1+2=6   
 3+2+1=6   

 1+2-3=0   
 1+3-2=2   
 2+1-3=0   
 2+3-1=4   
 3+1-2=2   
 3+2-1=4   

 1+2*3=7   
 1+3*2=7   
 2+1*3=5   
 2+3*1=5   
 3+1*2=5   
 3+2*1=5   

 1+2%3=5r3 
 1+3%2=5r2 
 2+1%3=7r3 
 2+3%1=5   
 3+1%2=7r2 
 3+2%1=5   

 1-2+3=_4  
 1-3+2=_4  
 2-1+3=_2  
 2-3+1=_2  
 3-1+2=0   
 3-2+1=0   

 1-2-3=2   
 1-3-2=0   
 2-1-3=4   
 2-3-1=0   
 3-1-2=4   
 3-2-1=2   

 1-2*3=_5  
 1-3*2=_5  
 2-1*3=_1  
 2-3*1=_1  
 3-1*2=1   
 3-2*1=1   

 1-2%3=1r3 
 1-3%2=_1r2
 2-1%3=5r3 
 2-3%1=_1  
 3-1%2=5r2 
 3-2%1=1   

 1*2+3=5   
 1*3+2=5   
 2*1+3=8   
 2*3+1=8   
 3*1+2=9   
 3*2+1=9   

 1*2-3=_1  
 1*3-2=1   
 2*1-3=_4  
 2*3-1=4   
 3*1-2=_3  
 3*2-1=3   

 1*2*3=6   
 1*3*2=6   
 2*1*3=6   
 2*3*1=6   
 3*1*2=6   
 3*2*1=6   

 1*2%3=2r3 
 1*3%2=3r2 
 2*1%3=2r3 
 2*3%1=6   
 3*1%2=3r2 
 3*2%1=6   

 1%2+3=1r5 
 1%3+2=1r5 
 2%1+3=1r2 
 2%3+1=1r2 
 3%1+2=1   
 3%2+1=1   

 1%2-3=_1  
 1%3-2=1   
 2%1-3=_1  
 2%3-1=1   
 3%1-2=_3  
 3%2-1=3   

 1%2*3=1r6 
 1%3*2=1r6 
 2%1*3=2r3 
 2%3*1=2r3 
 3%1*2=3r2 
 3%2*1=3r2 

 1%2%3=3r2 
 1%3%2=2r3 
 2%1%3=6   
 2%3%1=2r3 
 3%1%2=6   
 3%2%1=3r2
```

Comment: Integer Answers only round up at .5

Answer (score 10):

## C

600 bytes on disk with DOS line endings.

```
#define C B a,B b
#define D(N,O)B N(C){return a O b;}
#define E(A,B,C)i=A;j=B;k=C;X(m,p)X(m,m)X(t,t)X(d,t)X(t,d)X(d,d)Y(m,p)Y(p,p)Y(p,t)Y(p,d)Y(m,t)Y(m,d)
#define U"%.0f"
#define P(S,T)printf(U Z(S)U Z(T)U"="U"\n",v[i],v[j],v[k],
#define p +
#define m -
#define t *
#define d /
#define X(S,T)P(S,T)f##S(f##T(v[i],v[j]),v[k]));
#define Y(S,T)P(S,T)f##S(v[i],f##T(v[j],v[k])));
#define Z(A)#A
typedef double B;D(fp,+)D(fm,-)D(ft,*)B fd(C){return b?(int)(a/b+.5):-0.0;}main(int i,char*b[]){int j,k;B v[3]={atoi(b[1]),atoi(b[2]),atoi(b[3])};E(0,1,2)E(0,2,1)E(1,0,2)E(1,2,0)E(2,0,1)E(2,1,0)}
```

C doesn't seem to have NaN literals, so you get -0 if there's anything wrong rather than that.

However I think it fits the bill otherwise. (Note that the data type is `double` so that if it DID have a NaN in there, it will get printed out as such by `printf`.)

Comment: +1 for preprocessor abuse. But can you use atoi without a #include? Or indeed printf? My gcc doesn't like it.

Comment: Well they're undeclared, but that's fine, as both actually return int and the supplied arguments match what the routines expect. What errors do you get? (For best results, I guess compile as C89, turn off warnings about undeclared functions; I don't use gcc, so I couldn't say. Despite appearances though, there's actually nothing tricky about it...)

Comment: You're right, they're only warnings. For line 4: "missing whitespace after the macro name"; for line 13: "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’" The resulting executable runs fine.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript, 169 characters

(not counting unnecessary line breaks and indentation)

**Edit**: Now with input permutation

```
o=" ";i=i.split(o);z="+-*/";for(y=0;y<27;y++)for(x=0;x<16;x++){a=y/9|0;b=(y/3|0)%3;c=y%3;if(a!=b&&a!=c&&b!=c){s=i[a]+z[x/4|0]+i[b]+z[x%4]+i[c];o+=s+"="+~~(eval(s)+.5);}}
```

With indentation:

```
o=" ";
i=i.split(o);
z="+-*/";
for(y=0;y<27;y++)
for(x=0;x<16;x++)
{
    a=y/9|0;
    b=(y/3|0)%3;
    c=y%3;
    if(a!=b&&a!=c&&b!=c)
    {
        s=i[a]+z[x/4|0]+i[b]+z[x%4]+i[c];
        o+=s+"="+~~(eval(s)+.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could drop unnecessary formatting (HTML-wise) and lose a few more characters.

Comment: so far, this is the only one that doesn't have hard coded inputs.

Comment: but where does it do permutation for the input?

Comment: Well, part of the complexity of the problem is to evaluate the expression. If you use a built-in function to do it, you're missing half of the problem. It's also an unfair advantage over languages that don't have an eval function. See this discussion : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions/24258#24258

Comment: Um?  What?  Using features of a particular language is unfair?  Why bother selecting a language at all, if you can only use the features common to them all?  The whole *POINT* is to creatively select a language and approach to use the minimum number of characters.

Comment: I think the question itself is somewhat in violation of that quality point (no easy built-in solution), but that doesn't invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 6):

### Python - <strike>125</strike> <strike>175</strike> 177 characters:

(<strike>not</strike> now counting indentation)
Added command-line input, no more single-digit/non-zero restriction, works with zero (NaN)

```
import sys
from itertools import permutations as p
for i,j,k in p(sys.argv[1:4],3):
    for x,y in p('+-*/'*2,2):
        s=i+x+j+'.'+y+k
        try:e=eval(s)
        except:e='NaN'
        print s,'=',e
```

<strike>Still</strike> No more truncates instead of rounding up at 0.5

Comment: I don't think indentation should be omitted, since they're significant in Python.

Comment: -1: cannot handle `0` in its input in its current form (or values with more then one digit, e.g. `15`)

Comment: It is actually **134** chars when you count (you have to!) new lines and indentation. Does not work in python <2.6. Also the 3 values are hardcoded and can only be single-digit.

Comment: I've mentioned the truncation issue in the answer since the very beginning. What does Python 2.5 compatibility have to do with code golf?

Comment: Truncates results (so 9/10 will be 0 and not 1). See my solution further for idea on 'floating'. Alternatively can do eval(s.replace('/','./')) - since problem is only w/division and adding period will turn operand to float

Answer (score 4):

### Bash shell, <strike>126</strike> - <strike>169</strike> - <strike>156</strike> - 140 characters

Should work in any semi-modern Bash I think (tested with GNU bash, 3.2.48(1) x86_64-apple-build).

Handles division by zero (`Nan` case).

All suggestions and comments welcome!

```
for a in $@;do
s+={`echo $@|tr ' ' ,`}{+,-,*,/};done
for i in `eval echo ${s::${#s}-9}`;do
[[ $i == */0* ]]&&y=Nan||y=$[$i];echo $i=$y;done
```

Supply parameters via command line:

`./combinate.sh 5 0 12`

Comment: `sed 's/ /,/g'` can be reduced to `tr ' ' ','`

Comment: @dreamlax: good catch, thanks! (shaves off 5 characters when using `tr ' ' ,`)

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 105 <s>110</s> <s>142</s> <s>114</s> characters

```
o=%w{+ - * /};[*ARGV.permutation].product(o.product o).map{|x,y|e=x.zip(y)*"";p"#{e}=#{eval(e)rescue:N}"}
```

Usage

```
ruby prog.rb 1 2 3
```

Explanation

```
# o = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
o=%w{+ - * /};
# ARGV = array of numbers. Generate all permutations, and apply splat operator
[*ARGV.permutation]
# Generate cartesian product of all permuted numbers and operators 
# There will be 16 operator permutations, and 6 number permutations giving a 
# total of 96 elements
.product(o.product o)
# For each of the 96 pairs, merge the operators and numbers into 1 array.
# ex - [1,2,3].zip(["+", "-"]) gives [[1, '+'], [2, '-'], [3, nil]]
# then convert the array to string by multiplying with "" => "1+2-3"
.each{|x,y|e=x.zip(y)*"";
# print output and eval result. On exception return infinity - ∞
p"#{e}=#{eval(e)rescue:N}"}
```

Output

```
1+2+3=6
1+2-3=0
1+2*3=7
1+2/3=1
1-2+3=2
1-2-3=-4
1-2*3=-5
1-2/3=1
1*2+3=5
1*2-3=-1
1*2*3=6
1*2/3=0
1/2+3=3
1/2-3=-3
1/2*3=0
1/2/3=0
1+3+2=6
1+3-2=2
1+3*2=7
1+3/2=2
1-3+2=0
1-3-2=-4
1-3*2=-5
1-3/2=0
1*3+2=5
1*3-2=1
1*3*2=6
1*3/2=1
1/3+2=2
1/3-2=-2
1/3*2=0
1/3/2=0
2+1+3=6
2+1-3=0
2+1*3=5
2+1/3=2
2-1+3=4
2-1-3=-2
2-1*3=-1
2-1/3=2
2*1+3=5
2*1-3=-1
2*1*3=6
2*1/3=0
2/1+3=5
2/1-3=-1
2/1*3=6
2/1/3=0
2+3+1=6
2+3-1=4
2+3*1=5
2+3/1=5
2-3+1=0
2-3-1=-2
2-3*1=-1
2-3/1=-1
2*3+1=7
2*3-1=5
2*3*1=6
2*3/1=6
2/3+1=1
2/3-1=-1
2/3*1=0
2/3/1=0
3+1+2=6
3+1-2=2
3+1*2=5
3+1/2=3
3-1+2=4
3-1-2=0
3-1*2=1
3-1/2=3
3*1+2=5
3*1-2=1
3*1*2=6
3*1/2=1
3/1+2=5
3/1-2=1
3/1*2=6
3/1/2=1
3+2+1=6
3+2-1=4
3+2*1=5
3+2/1=5
3-2+1=2
3-2-1=0
3-2*1=1
3-2/1=1
3*2+1=7
3*2-1=5
3*2*1=6
3*2/1=6
3/2+1=2
3/2-1=0
3/2*1=1
3/2/1=1
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 221 chars

Argh!!, imports takes 50 chars.

```
import Data.List
import System
import Text.Printf
o=zip[(+),(-),(*),(/)]"+-*/"
main=do v<-getArgs;sequence[printf"%.0g%c(%.0g%c%.0g)=%.0g\n"x h y i z$f x$g y z|(f,h)<-o,(g,i)<-o,[x,y,z]<-permutations(map read v::[Float])]
```

`getArgs` needs System, `printf` needs Text.Printf, `permutations` needs Data.List, the `[[Float]]` is needed because `/` needs an instance of Fractional. We can't use `div` because it will throw when divide by zero.

Basically this just iterates over all possible combinations of operators and permutations of input arguments and print the result.

The three `%.0g` can be replaced by `%g` to remove 6 chars, but the result will look like `1.0/(2.0*3.0)=0` which is ugly.

---

```
~$ ./a.out 0 4 9
0+(4+9)=13
4+(0+9)=13
9+(4+0)=13
4+(9+0)=13
9+(0+4)=13
0+(9+4)=13
0+(4-9)=-5
4+(0-9)=-5
9+(4-0)=13
4+(9-0)=13
9+(0-4)=5
0+(9-4)=5
0+(4*9)=36
4+(0*9)=4
9+(4*0)=9
4+(9*0)=4
9+(0*4)=9
0+(9*4)=36
0+(4/9)=0
4+(0/9)=4
9+(4/0)=Infinity
4+(9/0)=Infinity
9+(0/4)=9
0+(9/4)=2
0-(4+9)=-13
4-(0+9)=-5
9-(4+0)=5
4-(9+0)=-5
9-(0+4)=5
0-(9+4)=-13
0-(4-9)=5
4-(0-9)=13
9-(4-0)=5
4-(9-0)=-5
9-(0-4)=13
0-(9-4)=-5
0-(4*9)=-36
4-(0*9)=4
9-(4*0)=9
4-(9*0)=4
9-(0*4)=9
0-(9*4)=-36
0-(4/9)=-0
4-(0/9)=4
9-(4/0)=-Infinity
4-(9/0)=-Infinity
9-(0/4)=9
0-(9/4)=-2
0*(4+9)=0
4*(0+9)=36
9*(4+0)=36
4*(9+0)=36
9*(0+4)=36
0*(9+4)=0
0*(4-9)=-0
4*(0-9)=-36
9*(4-0)=36
4*(9-0)=36
9*(0-4)=-36
0*(9-4)=0
0*(4*9)=0
4*(0*9)=0
9*(4*0)=0
4*(9*0)=0
9*(0*4)=0
0*(9*4)=0
0*(4/9)=0
4*(0/9)=0
9*(4/0)=Infinity
4*(9/0)=Infinity
9*(0/4)=0
0*(9/4)=0
0/(4+9)=0
4/(0+9)=0
9/(4+0)=2
4/(9+0)=0
9/(0+4)=2
0/(9+4)=0
0/(4-9)=-0
4/(0-9)=-0
9/(4-0)=2
4/(9-0)=0
9/(0-4)=-2
0/(9-4)=0
0/(4*9)=0
4/(0*9)=Infinity
9/(4*0)=Infinity
4/(9*0)=Infinity
9/(0*4)=Infinity
0/(9*4)=0
0/(4/9)=0
4/(0/9)=Infinity
9/(4/0)=0
4/(9/0)=0
9/(0/4)=Infinity
0/(9/4)=0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl - 76 characters

```
$a=1;$b=2;$c=3;
warn eval for map{$x=$_;map"$a$x$b$_$c",@a}@a=split//,'+-/*';
```

Comment: Nice job. How about the 0.5 rounding and format printing now?

Comment: And not hard-coding the inputs. (Costs 2 chars I think.)

Comment: :) with rounding and user input, 85: ($a,$b,$c)=@ARGV;map{$x=$_;map printf("%.0f\n",eval"$a$x$b$_$c"),@a}@a=split//,"+-/*"

Comment: how does it permute the input?

Comment: There's printing the string expression first. Also, this doesn't permute the numbers, which the spec requires.

Answer (score 2):

### Lua - 240 characters

Note: Prints 1.#INF and -1.#INF instead of NaN.

```
a,b,c=...o="+-*/"f=function(...)g=table.concat({...})loadstring('x='..g)()print(g..' = '..math.floor(x+.5))end for d in o:gmatch(".")do for e in o:gmatch(".")do f(a,d,b,e,c)f(a,d,c,e,b)f(b,d,a,e,c)f(b,d,c,e,a)f(c,d,a,e,b)f(c,d,b,e,a)end end
```

#### Output

```
5+0+13 = 18
5+13+0 = 18
0+5+13 = 18
0+13+5 = 18
13+5+0 = 18
13+0+5 = 18
5+0-13 = -8
5+13-0 = 18
0+5-13 = -8
0+13-5 = 8
13+5-0 = 18
13+0-5 = 8
5+0*13 = 5
5+13*0 = 5
0+5*13 = 65
0+13*5 = 65
13+5*0 = 13
13+0*5 = 13
5+0/13 = 5
5+13/0 = 1.#INF
0+5/13 = 0
0+13/5 = 3
13+5/0 = 1.#INF
13+0/5 = 13
5-0+13 = 18
5-13+0 = -8
0-5+13 = 8
0-13+5 = -8
13-5+0 = 8
13-0+5 = 18
5-0-13 = -8
5-13-0 = -8
0-5-13 = -18
0-13-5 = -18
13-5-0 = 8
13-0-5 = 8
5-0*13 = 5
5-13*0 = 5
0-5*13 = -65
0-13*5 = -65
13-5*0 = 13
13-0*5 = 13
5-0/13 = 5
5-13/0 = -1.#INF
0-5/13 = 0
0-13/5 = -3
13-5/0 = -1.#INF
13-0/5 = 13
5*0+13 = 13
5*13+0 = 65
0*5+13 = 13
0*13+5 = 5
13*5+0 = 65
13*0+5 = 5
5*0-13 = -13
5*13-0 = 65
0*5-13 = -13
0*13-5 = -5
13*5-0 = 65
13*0-5 = -5
5*0*13 = 0
5*13*0 = 0
0*5*13 = 0
0*13*5 = 0
13*5*0 = 0
13*0*5 = 0
5*0/13 = 0
5*13/0 = 1.#INF
0*5/13 = 0
0*13/5 = 0
13*5/0 = 1.#INF
13*0/5 = 0
5/0+13 = 1.#INF
5/13+0 = 0
0/5+13 = 13
0/13+5 = 5
13/5+0 = 3
13/0+5 = 1.#INF
5/0-13 = 1.#INF
5/13-0 = 0
0/5-13 = -13
0/13-5 = -5
13/5-0 = 3
13/0-5 = 1.#INF
5/0*13 = 1.#INF
5/13*0 = 0
0/5*13 = 0
0/13*5 = 0
13/5*0 = 0
13/0*5 = 1.#INF
5/0/13 = 1.#INF
5/13/0 = 1.#INF
0/5/13 = 0
0/13/5 = 0
13/5/0 = 1.#INF
13/0/5 = 1.#INF
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, it's not really short, but I post it anyway, just for fun...

Note that unlike most other answers, this one doesn't use `eval` since it's not available in C# (it would be much shorter with it)

### C#, 729 chars

```
using System;using System.Linq;using w=System.Double;class Op{public char c;public int p;public Func<w,w,w>f;}class Program{static void Main(string[]p){var nb=p.Select((n,i)=>new{n=w.Parse(n),i});var op=new[]{new Op{c='+',p=0,f=(a,b)=>a+b},new Op{c='-',p=0,f=(a,b)=>a-b},new Op{c='*',p=1,f=(a,b)=>a*b},new Op{c='/',p=1,f=(a,b)=>a/b},};Func<Op,Op,Func<w,w,w,w>>fg=(o1,o2)=>(x,y,z)=>o1.p>=o2.p?o2.f(o1.f(x,y),z):o1.f(x,o2.f(y,z));Func<w,w>nan=d=>w.IsInfinity(d)?w.NaN:d;var res=from o1 in op from o2 in op from x in nb from y in nb where x.i!=y.i from z in nb where z.i!=x.i&&z.i!=y.i let r=nan(fg(o1,o2)(x.n,y.n,z.n))select string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}={5:F0}",x.n,o1.c,y.n,o2.c,z.n,r);res.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);}}
```

**Expanded version**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using w=System.Double;

// Operator class
// c = character
// p = priority
// f = function
class Op { public char c; public int p; public Func<w, w, w> f; }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Parse the input and associate each number with its index
        var nb = args.Select((n, i) => new { n = w.Parse(n), i });

        // Operators definition
        var op = new[]
        {
            new Op { c = '+', p = 0, f = (a, b) => a + b },
            new Op { c = '-', p = 0, f = (a, b) => a - b },
            new Op { c = '*', p = 1, f = (a, b) => a * b },
            new Op { c = '/', p = 1, f = (a, b) => a / b },
        };

        // Function generator to compute the result ; handles operator priority
        Func<Op, Op, Func<w, w, w, w>> fg =
            (o1, o2) =>
                (x, y, z) =>
                    o1.p >= o2.p
                        ? o2.f(o1.f(x, y), z)
                        : o1.f(x, o2.f(y, z));

        // Converts +/- Infinity to NaN
        Func<w, w> nan = d => w.IsInfinity(d) ? w.NaN : d;

        // Results
        var res =
            // Combinations of 2 operators
            from o1 in op
            from o2 in op
            // Permutations of numbers
            from x in nb
            from y in nb
            where x.i != y.i
            from z in nb
            where z.i != x.i && z.i != y.i
            // Compute result
            let r = nan(fg(o1, o2)(x.n, y.n, z.n))
            // Format output
            select string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} = {5:F0}", x.n, o1.c, y.n, o2.c, z.n, r);

        res.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Who said you can't do functional programming in C# ? ;)

---

EDIT : fixed to make it work with duplicate numbers

Comment: @Dykam: fixed it. didn't test it though.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the space in `Func<w,w,w> f`? Then it has the same length as Java ;)

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer, thanks for the fix. I tested in LinqPad so I omitted the usual program structure... Regarding your second comment, you can add a few more '+' signs ;). @KennyTM, yes it is possible, I removed it. Thanks !

Comment: -1 Your solution don't support the same number in the input: `1 2 2`.

Comment: @stacker, indeed, I had missed that case... it's fixed now

Answer (score 2):

**F#: 280 chars, incl. newlines**

The unreadable version:

```
let q s=System.Data.DataTable().Compute(s,"")|>string|>float
let e(a,b,c)=let o=["+";"-";"*";"/"]in for x in o do for y in o do let s=a+x+b+y+c in printfn"%s=%.0f"s (q s)
[<EntryPoint>]let p(A:_[])=(for i=0 to 2 do let p,q,r=A.[i],A.[(i+1)%3],A.[(i+2)%3]in e(p,q,r);e(p,r,q));0
```

The tl;dr version:

```
//This program needs to be compiled as a console project
//It needs additional references to System.Data and System.Xml

//This function evaluates a string expression to a float
//It (ab)uses the Compute method of System.Data.DataTable which acts 
//as .Net's own little eval()
let q s =
    //the answer is an object
    System.Data.DataTable().Compute(s,"")
    //so convert it to a string and then parse it as a float
    |> string
    |> float

//This function first generates all 6 permutations of a 3-tuple of strings
//and then inserts all operator combination between the entries
//Finally it prints the expression and its evaluated result
let e (a,b,c) =
    let o = ["+";"-";"*";"/"] 
    //a double loop to get all operator combos
    for x in o 
        do for y in o do 
            let s=a+x+b+y+c //z is expression to evaluate
            //print the result as expression = result, 
            //the %.0f formatter takes care of rounding
            printfn "%s=%.0f" s (q s)

//This is the entry point definition. 
//A is the array of command line args as strings.
[<EntryPoint>]
let p(A:_[]) = 
    //Generate all permutations: 
    //for each index i: 
    //  put the i-th element at the front and add the two remaining elements
    //  once in original order and once swapped. Voila: 6 permutations.
    for i=0 to 2 do 
        let p,q,r = A.[i], A.[(i+1)%3], A.[(i+2)%3] 
        e(p,q,r) //evaluate and print "p + <op> + q + <another op> + r"
        e(p,r,q) //evaluate and print "p + <op> + r + <another op> + q"
    0 //the execution of the program apparently needs to return an integer
```

Example output:

```
> ConsoleApplication1 1 2 0
1+2+0=3
1+2-0=3
1+2*0=1
1+2/0=Infinity
1-2+0=-1
1-2-0=-1
1-2*0=1
1-2/0=-Infinity
1*2+0=2
1*2-0=2
1*2*0=0
1*2/0=Infinity
1/2+0=1
1/2-0=1
1/2*0=0
1/2/0=Infinity
1+0+2=3
1+0-2=-1
1+0*2=1
1+0/2=1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby

(reads from argument list and returns NaN if not divisible)

(would be only the last line if ruby had a permutation library)

```
class Array
  def perm(n = size)
    if size < n or n < 0
    elsif n == 0
      yield([])
    else
      self[1..-1].perm(n - 1) do |x|
        (0...n).each do |i|
          yield(x[0...i] + [first] + x[i..-1])
        end
      end
      self[1..-1].perm(n) do |x|
        yield(x)
      end
    end
  end
end

ARGV.perm(3){|a,b,c| "++//**--".split(//).perm(2){ |d,e| x=a+d+b+e+c;puts "#{x} = #{eval(x)}" rescue puts "#{x} = NaN"} }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python (171 characters)

This avoids shortfalls of previous python solution (hard-coded 1-digit numbers only, dependency on newer libraries). Reads from stdin - if you want cmdline, replace "raw_input().split()" with "sys.argv[1:4]"

```
x=raw_input().split()
for e in[x[i/3]+p+x[i%3]+'.'+q+x[3-i/3-i%3]for i in range(9)if i%4for p in'+-*/'for q in'+-*/']:
    try:r=round(eval(e))
    except:r='NaN'
    print e,'=',r
```

ps. decreased to 147->138
pps. changed calculations from int to float w/rounding, 138->153
ppps. added support for /0=NaN,  153->179
pppps. decreased 179->177
ppppps. sacrificed beauty for brevity, 177->171

Comment: What is that `<>` operator in Python?

Comment: yeah, <> and != mean the same in Python, "not equal".
"!=" is C-like and used also in Java, Perl etc.

"<>" is Basic-like and also used in Pascal, SQL, *ML etc

Comment: now it does work for /0. AND it rounds correctly. ...and does not use some newly fangled library function :-D

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 584 bytes

(includes necessary indentation and LFs)

```
let d a b=if b=0.0 then nan else a/b
let o=["*",((*),1);"+",((+),0);"/",(d,1);"-",((-),0)]
let b=double
let rec z=function|[x]->[x,[]]|x::s->(x,s)::List.map(fun(y,l)->y,x::l)(z s)
let rec p=function|[]->[[]]|l->z l|>List.collect(fun(x,r)->p r|>List.map(fun l->x::l))
let f=fst
let e o p x y z=if snd o<snd p then (f o)x ((f p) y z) else (f p)((f o) x y)z
[<EntryPoint>]let m a=
for i in p(Seq.toList a)do
 let x,y,z=b i.[0],b i.[1],b i.[2]
 for j in[for j in o do for k in o do yield[j;k]]do
  printfn "%.0f%s%.0f%s%.0f = %.0f" x (f j.[0])y (f j.[1])z (e(snd j.[0])(snd j.[1])x y z)
0
```

Kudos to [kvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82959/kvb) for his/her [permutations function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526046/f-permutations/1526208#1526208).

It wound up being quite similar in structure to [Thomas' C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960242/code-golf-all-combinations-for-3-integers/2962641#2962641) (maybe because his solution is already quite functional)