# Find all variations of letters in a word in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

In a program used to find words from random scrabble letters how do you loop through each of the possible combinations of letters? ie: abc acb bac bca cab cba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is permute the set of characters contained within the string.

There's a question here about it:

[Find string permutation including the single character using C# or F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237934/find-string-permutation-including-the-single-character-using-c-sharp-or-f)

Comment: Yes the example solution is in C#, but as its linq its pretty much the same anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that permutation was a method