# Itertools for F#

Tags: f#, python-itertools

I'm used to [Python's itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for doing functional things with iterators (F#: sequences) and wondered if there were equivalents in F# or a commonly used library since they're so handy.

The top tools for me are:

- product : cartesian product, equivalent to a nested for-loop
- combinations
- permutations
- takewhile
- dropwhile
- chain : chain multiple iterators together into a new longer iterator
- repeat* : repeat(5) -> 5, 5, 5...
- count* : count(10) -> 10, 11, 12...
- cycle* : cycle([1,2,3]) -> 1,2,3,1,2...

* I suppose these 3 would yield monads in F#? How do you make them infinite?

I'm prompted to ask because I saw [this question on permutations in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/286427/36537) and was surprised it was not part of a library or built into the language.

Comment: `TakeWhile`, `dropwhile` chaining and repeating are all included in the default F# libs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there's a commonly used library that contains functions like product, combinations and permutations, but the others you've mentioned are already in `Seq` and `List` modules or can be implemented without much trouble, and there are also useful methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

- `takewhile` -> `Seq.takeWhile`
- `dropwhile` -> `Seq.skipWhile`
- `chain` -> `Seq.concat`
- `repeat` -> `Seq.initInfinite`
- `count(10)` -> `Seq.initInfinite ((+) 10)`
- `cycle([1, 2, 3])` -> `Seq.concat <| Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> [1; 2; 3])`

You also might want to check out the excellent FSharpx library -- it contains a lot of useful functions to work with collections and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

For a cartesian product in F# (avoiding a nested for loop ^_^), you need to use List.allPairs list1 list2 :

https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#allPairs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.